# The All clause Core data Predicate does not work as expected

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I am having my core data model like this:

> EntityA <---->> EntityB <<----> EntityC

Now, I want to get objects of `EntityB` where `EntityC == nil`.

I have thought about a lot of options:

The one I tried is:

`ANY EntityB.EntityC == nil`

Though this does not give an error, it does not work how I expect, because this searches all objects of `EntityA`, and even if one is not `nil`, it takes that object of `EntityA`.

So what I tried is:

`ALL Participant.ParticipantCategory == nil`

but this gives an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate (null)

I also tried using SubQueries, but did not work out. I have spent hours trying to solve it but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the subquery you have tried?

Comment: This is the subquery: SUBQUERY(Participant, $part, part.ParticipantCategory == nil).@count > 0. For this, I get this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath part.ParticipantCategory not found in entity <NSSQLEntity XYZEntity id=2>

Comment: Here, entityB would be Participant and EntityC would be ParticipantCategory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your predicate should be just: `Participant.ParticipantCategory == nil`

`ANY` keyword is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html). I think it is behaving as it should. And I'm not aware of an `ALL` keyword.

Comment: No Luck Paul :( I already had tried that. I get this error if I do:Participant.ParticipantCategory == nil:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'. Any other thoughts?

Comment: If it is a to-many relationship. Try Participant.ParticipantCategory.@count == 0

Comment: Thanks a ton Paul. It worked!! I did not know of such a thing though.

Comment: My bad, it did not work out well in all cases. Still tinkering over the problem.

Comment: @PauldeLange thanks a lot !!!! was breaking my head over this. I wish you could post this as an answer